# Is full Angular theme allowed in WordPress marketplaces?

Tags: wordpress, angular, wordpress-theming

I interested if I spend time and energy on creating a full Angular theme for WordPress, then is it allowed to sell on famous WordPress theme marketplaces?

Since the full Angular theme does not follow WordPress theme hierarchy and maybe there are conflicts with lots of WordPress plugins, going to be accepted these type of themes are very difficult.

- Have you seen any such templates?
- Is there any way to pass theme review tests for Angular themes?

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't appear to be anything that explicitly prevents an Angular theme.

https://make.wordpress.org/themes/handbook/review/

The main items would be ensuring content creation in WordPress is routed properly and displayed with the Angular theme.

You could use the Xo for Angular plugin to provide all the necessary integrations.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/xo-for-angular/

Xo also allows the dynamic insertion of wp_head and wp_footer into your index so other plugins are still compatible with your Angular theme.

Here is an example theme built using Xo for Angular which I plan to submit to the WordPress themes repository soon.

https://github.com/WarriorRocker/angular-xo-material

I am the author of the plugin and theme above.